# ext-gmp is not enabled error, shows enabled on phpinfo

Tags: php

So I am trying to install the blocktrail API via composer and it throws this error :-

```
 Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-gmp * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gmp extension.
```

However, PHP GMP is actually installed and show as Enabled when I run phpinfo(); What might might be wrong in here?

Comment: Have you definitely enabled the extension for the CLI SAPI?

Comment: @iainn

I'm sorry but I dont understand. Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: PHP extensions have to be enabled for each "environment", or SAPI. It sounds like you've enabled GMP for your webserver (Apache or Nginx, etc), but not for the command-line, which is what Composer uses to check your system. Try running `php -m` and see if GMP is listed.

Comment: @iainn

Oops, it' doesnsn't show there. What could I do to enable it?

Comment: We can't say for sure without knowing more about your system and the PHP version, etc. On Ubuntu it would be something like `sudo phpenmod -s CLI gmp`, or you might just need to uncomment a line in `php.ini (something like *extension=gmp.so*).

Comment: @iainn

I'm running on a macbook with php 5.6